# Finding common mode level and max output swing in two stage op-amp

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit

[image]

I just want a hint on how to even start attempting this question. I wasn't able to link any equation to the given values in the question. Felt like too much was unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the task data are incomplete or at least formulated tacitly -- depends on the context of your project. The design uses short channel MOSFETs (lenth < 2u), but if you absolutely need to attempt this task, you can start and replace transistors with the simplest MOSFET model (longchannel and without channel length modulation) as a voltage controlled current source (similar to technique used in an answer to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229062/mosfet-as-a-vccs-or-an-variable-resistance) question)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgk2qo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

`I_DS = 0                                       V_GS < V_Thresh`

`I_DS = beta·(V_GS – V_Thresh – V_DS/2)·V_DS    V_GS > V_Thresh , V_DS < V_DSAT`

`I_DS = (beta/2)·(V_GS – V_Thresh )^2           V_GS > V_Thresh , V_DS > VDSAT`

`V_DSAT = V_GS – V_Thresh`

For pMOS, change signs to accommodate device polarity.

`beta = u0 (carrier mobility) * Cox (oxide capacitance) * W/L`

You can find V_Thresh, u0, and Cox parameter values in reference documents, e.g. [Star-HSpice Manual](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Emoon/ece323/hspice98/files/chapter_16.pdf).

Typical V_Thresh are 0.45V for nMOS and 1V for pMOS; the default u0 are 2.0718e-5 (NMOS) and 8.632e-6 (PMOS), Cox about 0.00035 Farade/square meter.

If you succeed in this undoubtedly useful exercise, you can further attempt more advanced transistor models.

A regular approach to analysis of electronic designs is the use of simulators (SPICE/PSPICE/HSPICE, Cadence Spectre X simulator, Mentor AMS simulator, other high-end packages and numerous free tools).